# directive with `this` doesnt give current element angular js

Tags: angularjs, keypress, angular-directive

I'm using this directive in angular js to track an enter keypress

```
angular.module('botApp').directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

but when I try this on an input element (which is inside an ng-repeat)

```
<input id="inp-test_text" class="default-input inp-loading" type="text" 
       name="test_text" ng-model="app.test_text"
       my-enter="inputEnter(this)">
```

and in js I have:

```
   $scope.inputEnter = function(currentInput) {
        console.log(currentInput);
    }
```

I get this as an answer:

[image: console-log of currentInput]

So I get everything except the current input information. How do I get the element of which I pressed enter on? ($event, $element doesn't work as parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) , the identifier `this` accesses the context object which in the case of [`$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) is the `scope` object.

To provide the local `element`, add it as a local:

```
app.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶e̶v̶a̶l̶(̶a̶t̶t̶r̶s̶.̶m̶y̶E̶n̶t̶e̶r̶)̶;̶
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter, {$element: element});
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Then it will be available as a local:

```
<input id="inp-test_text" class="default-input inp-loading" type="text" 
       name="test_text" ng-model="app.test_text"
       ̶m̶y̶-̶e̶n̶t̶e̶r̶=̶"̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶E̶n̶t̶e̶r̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶)̶"̶
       my-enter="inputEnter($element)">
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context)
- [AngularJS `scope.$eval` API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

Comment: Sorry i forgot!

Comment: Under the hood, the [`scope.$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) uses the `$parse` service. For more information, see [AngularJS `$parse` Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).